# Are there any other queues in the standard library?

Tags: python, queue, producer-consumer, thunk

I want to queue

```
lambda : Popen(.....)
```

To call/wait at a later time.
Then add some more to paused Popens to the queue,
then consume them again and so on.

The main Queue module cares a lot about synchronization and this makes
the api feel a bit weird in places. I don't care about syncing(single threaded
program, Popen just do their job and throw exception on error and they don't affect
the environment in any important ways(they generate files)

Should I just use a generator that I add to it at a later time.
If so whats a good way to add items to generators, calling

```
gena = itertools.chain(gena,[item))
```

each time seems wastefull.

Comment: Question: is the downvote because of a bad description or?

Comment: Lack of research.  A Google search for `Python queue` returns the desired answer as the second entry, right after the Queue class.  And a word search for queue in the Library Reference Manual, after hitting heapq and queue in the table of contents, finds deque in the collections section.

Comment: I tried and missed maybe because I was tired. I remembered something like "It is also possible to use a list as a queue," but use this instead from reading it some time ago but when I searched the docs before I couldn't find it again.

Comment: Now that I look on google the 3rd link(2nd top level link) does point to that passage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a deque (collections.deque), which is a list that you can efficiently push and pop on either end. You could also use a list and not worry about the inefficiency since it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Good ahnswer - I vill [Pump you Up](http://www.hulu.com/watch/4184/saturday-night-live-pumping-up-with-hans-and-franz)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

queue = deque()
queue.append(new) # append
current = queue.popleft() # first item
```

Comment: Good ahnswer too, [Girly Man](http://www.hulu.com/watch/4184/saturday-night-live-pumping-up-with-hans-and-franz)

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't concerned about multi-threading, the logical choice would seem to be [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque).